# Not able to implement Docusign SDK

Tags: java, docusignapi

Getting error when initializing DocuSign ApiClient

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/docusign/esign/client/ApiClient
    at org.jitterbit.connector.docusign.DocuSignConnection.open(DocuSignConnection.java:69)
```

Comment: NoClassDef occurs when the compile time classes arent available in the runtime. Cna you check if your runtime env has the jars?

Answer (score 2):

you need to find the jar file of the DocuSign eSign library (https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.docusign) and make sure it's installed as part of your project. If you are using Eclipse this is how you add the jar to your project:

1. Right click on your project.
2. Select Build Path.
3. Click on Configure Build Path.
4. Click on Libraries and select Add External JARs.
5. Select the jar file from the required folder.
6. Click and Apply and Ok.